# Convert Number in column to specific word in RDLC C#

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer

I need to know how I can convert a result of a column that is in my RDLC in a text.

For example : My RDLC file is displaying some columns from a table of my database where one of them is called Status and has three values ​​( 0 , 1, 2 ) and I need instead of displaying the value 1 displays " Call Open " .

I need to reformulate my Select I am doing in the database or can perform this conversion in RDLC ?

I conducted some research and saw that I can insert a direct code in RDLC file but do not even know which command start

*** UPDATE ***

Now I'm trying to use the Expression mentioned by Bruce Cam click on the right button in the column and entering the following code : IIF(Fields!StatusChamado.Value = 1, "Call Open", IIF(Fields!StatusChamado.Value = 2, "Call Closed", "Fallback Status"))

But it is apparently removing the DS ( DataSource ) named StatusChamado and writing the code itself in the column without presenting results , I'm skipping any steps to enter the Excession in RDLC ?

*** UPDATE ***

Problem solved, it was the Missing Signal = Before the IIF .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options.

- If your status names are in the database, you can change your SQL/SPROC to use a `CASE` statement or join to the appropriate table on your status id, then include the status name in your updated dataset.
- If the status names are hard coded, each column can be an expression. In your expression, you would use a nested `IIF` or `SWITCH` expression, like this:

`=IIF(Fields!Status.Value = 1, "Call Open", IIF(Fields!Status.Value = 2, "Call Closed", "Fallback Status"))`

Comment: I believe that using expression is more practical than I redo the select in my database.

I clicked right column and Expression enter the command, but he removed the DataSource of my column ( [ StatusChamado ] ) , and entered all the code text and did not work.

Is there a trick to set this Expression ?

Comment: Can you update your post with the expression you used?

Comment: Problem solved, it was the Missing Signal = Before the IIF , thanks for the help